# Code doesn't run when user inputs whitespace

Tags: java, char

My program takes a character and describes the input in mutliple ways (character is uppercase, character is lowercase, etc.) My code needs to detect when user inputs whitespace and print "character is whitespace." However, whenever I enter in a space my code won't even run. Sorry that this is a basic question. My current code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputCharacterInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myChar = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a character...");

        char aChar = myChar.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("The character is " + aChar);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(aChar))
            System.out.println(aChar + " is uppercase");
        else
            System.out.println(aChar + " is not uppercase");
        if (Character.isLowerCase(aChar))
            System.out.println(aChar + " is lowercase");
        else
            System.out.println(aChar + " is not lowercase");
        aChar = Character.toLowerCase(aChar);
        System.out.println("After tolowerCase(), aChar is " + aChar);
        aChar = Character.toUpperCase(aChar);
        System.out.println("After toUpperCase(), aChar is " + aChar);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(aChar))
            System.out.println(aChar + " is a letter or digit");
        else
            System.out.println(aChar +
                    " is neither a letter nor a digit");

        if (Character.isWhitespace(aChar))
            System.out.println(aChar + " is whitespace");
        else
            System.out.println(aChar + " is not whitespace");
    }
}
```

The code needs to detect the user inputted white space and print "character is whitespace" or "character is not whitespace." I put enter into the console and the code doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is because `Scanner.next()` reads the next token, and tokens are defined by a separator. [The default separator is whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--:%7E:text=A%20Scanner%20breaks%20its%20input%20into%20tokens%20using%20a%20delimiter%20pattern%2C%20which%20by%20default%20matches%20whitespace), so it keeps waiting for more so that it can grab a full token.

For example, take the following prompt, where I enter space a bunch of times, hit enter a couple of times with lines only with spaces then I enter some letters before hitting enter:

```
Enter a character...
    
   
   
  asdasdfasfa asdasd as dasd
```

Unwrapping the following code `char aChar = myChar.next().charAt(0);`:

```
myChar.next() -> waits until it can complete a token, which is delimited by whitespace
                 finally gets `asdasdfasfa`
"asdasdfasfa".charAt(0) -> 'a'
```

A possible solution is to define a different delimiter for next, one that will parse even a single space, the empty delimiter:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myChar = new Scanner(System.in);
    myChar.useDelimiter(""); // <----------- SET DELIMITER AS EMPTY STRING
    System.out.println("Enter a character...");
```

If we now input " aasdf" to your program, your `next()` will return only " ", and another later `next()` call would return "a", until you `next()` enough to "f", where another `next()` call would give us a newline character (our hitting enter), and then another `next()` call would finally hang again.

If you prefer not grabbing newline characters, it would be easier to use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--), without changing the delimiter:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myChar = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a character...");
    char aChar = myChar.nextLine().charAt(0);  // <---- nextLine instead of next
```